# jquery tabs selected is not working

Tags: jquery, cookies, tabs

I have 2 tabs and would like to select the 2nd as selected/active. I don't know what is the difference between active/selected but this code doesn't work:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs({ selected: "#tabs-1" });
});
```

I changed it to:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs({ selected: 2 });
});
```

and change the selected: 2 to 1 or 0 but no luck.

**I would when the user clicks a tab, cookie should record the selection and when visitor visits next time, the remembered tab should be active.**
thanks

Answer (score 4):

selected is not a valid attribute for the jQuery UI tabs widget.  You need to use active.
http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

The reason this code doesn't work is because you initialize the tabs widget twice:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs(); //initialize tabs without specifying selected.
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({ selected: 2 }); //doesn't work
});
```

Either do this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({ active: 2 });
});
```

or this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 2 );
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  the code $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 2 ); it works perfect.